# Output SQL Query on Classic ASP page

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following query running on a classic asp page.

```
sSQL = "Select ProductID, SUM(Quantity) FROM OrderDetails Where CAST(orderDate AS DATE) Between '"&sStartDate&"' And '"&sEndDate&"' GROUP BY ProductID"
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open sSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

<tr>
<td>
<%Response.Write(rs.Fields("ProductID"))%>
</td>
<td>
What is the code to get the sum of the quantity here?
</td>
```

How do I output the quantity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sSQL = "Select ProductID, SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity FROM OrderDetails Where CAST(orderDate AS DATE) Between '"&sStartDate&"' And '"&sEndDate&"' GROUP BY ProductID"
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open sSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

<tr>
<td>
<%Response.Write(rs.Fields("ProductID"))%>
</td>
<td>
<%= rs.Fields("TotalQuantity") %>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Jinesh, I was totally overlooking the obvious.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ordinal values to access your fields

`<%= rs.Fields(1) %>`

You could also change your sql query to something like

Select ProductID, SUM(Quantity) As Quantity...

and then you would have access to this column name

`<%= rs.Fields(Quantity) %>`